# installed LetoDMS how do I change the data storage to a designated hard drive?

Tags: 14.04, configuration, software-installation

I installed [LetoDMS](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/base/letodms) from the Ubuntu software center on a 14.04 ubuntu desktop. everything seems to go okay but I can't figure out how to change the document storage to a specific drive that I set aside for this purpose. does anyone know how to do this? the info on the site is not specific enough for me to be sure where to start at after it's been installed this way.

Thanks for your patience and time for a newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from this page [http://www.letodms.com/doc/doku.php?id=install:install](http://www.letodms.com/doc/doku.php?id=install%3ainstall) it seems to me that you're talking about the folder created in step 3.

It then says in step 7 to set variable `$_contentDir` to the path to the folder created in step 3.

Can't you create a content folder on the drive you want and set $_contentDir to the corresponding path?

`$_contentDir` is to be set in `<path to letoDMS>/inc/inc.Settings.php` apparently.

By the way I think letoDMS is not active anymore, but SeedDMS is its continuation (http://www.seeddms.org).

Comment: thankyou I did not know that seeddms is the continuation. Ill try that